# File list isn't displayng while using find with -maxdepth 1 to remove subfolders

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to run the following code

```
FILESIZE="+30M"
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -size "$FILESIZE" -type f -exec echo "put {}" \;
```

in order to get a list of file paths in the folder `$1` excluding subfolders. But this code generates zero output. Without `-maxdepth 1` list of documents in the `$1` folder is displaying fine.

Script is located at `/mnt/d/`, documents are located at `/mnt/d/Documents and docs/`. So I am running this command

```
bash /mnt/d/script.sh "/mnt/d/Documents and docs"
```

This code generates zero output, instead of displaying the list of matching documents (near 50).
Where do I have an error?

---

EDIT1:
Putting `set -x` in the beginning of the script gave me the following:

```
+ FILESIZE=+30M
+ find '/mnt/d/Documents and docs/' -maxdepth 1 -size +30M -type f -exec echo 'put {}' ';'
```

EDIT2: When removing -maxdepth 1 the output is

```
+ FILESIZE=+30M
+ find '/mnt/d/Documents and docs/' -size +30M -type f -exec echo 'put {}' ';'
put /mnt/d/Documents and docs/Docs/1.doc
put /mnt/d/Documents and docs/Docs/2.doc
put /mnt/d/Documents and docs/Docs/3.doc
...
put /mnt/d/Documents and docs/Docs/50.doc
```

EDIT3: Just discovered I've forgotten about another subfolder in Documents and docs/

When running `bash /mnt/d/script.sh "/mnt/d/Documents and docs/Docs/"` everything is working fine.

Comment: It looks like it should work. Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to see a transcript with variables filled in.

Comment: @Barmar I've got the following:

Comment: It looks like you must have done `set FILESIZE="+30M"` instead of just `FILESIZE="+30M"`. This command sets `$1`.

Comment: @Barmar, why it is using the first line as a $1?

Comment: Please put the full transcript into the question, not a comment.

Comment: @Barmar , done. Why `$1` shouldn't be the file path from the argument?

Comment: I know. But if you use the `set` command with no options, it replaces the arguments.

Comment: The only explanation is that you have `set FILESIZE="+30M"` in the script, not what you posted in the question.

Comment: @Barmar Should I put a new line after `set -x`?

Comment: Of course you should. It's a separate command.

Comment: Is the directory really named `Documents and docs`? Your transcript originally had a name with Cyrillic characters in it. Does it work if you use a directory with only ASCII characters?

Comment: Updated once again

Comment: @Barmar nope, it's not.

Comment: I don't see anything new since 5 minutes ago.

Comment: @Barmar Directory really named Documents and docs

Comment: The transcript seems to be correct.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it's not working.

Comment: Show the output when you don't use `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: @Barmar updated post. Everything is working now! Thank you!

Comment: Glad you solved it.